# Can PowerShell open a file explorer window and have that window do a recursive search for specific file types?

Tags: powershell, search

What I'm looking to do is to open an explorer window for a specific folder for the user.  That explorer window is already set to recursively search within that specific folder for all .exe and .msu files.  The purpose of this is so the user can manually delete any files that are not needed.  Once the user is done they close the explorer window and the script moves onto the processing of all the files that remained in the specific folder.

Example:

Open explorer to C:\temp

Search recursively for *.exe and *.msu

Files Found :

```
C:\temp\a.exe
C:\temp\b.exe 
C:\temp\msu\c.msu
C:\temp\msu\d.msu
```

Script pauses

User manually deletes:

```
a.exe
c.msu
```

User closes explorer window

script continues

I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to do this with an actual explorer window but would just popping up a list of files in a WPF dialog work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Out-GridView` to show found items and select them to delete (or Cancel to skip). Sample:

```
Write-Host -f Green 'Start script'

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp' -Include '*.exe','*.msu' -Recurse | 
    select -ExpandProperty Fullname | 
        Out-GridView -Title 'Select files to delete' -PassThru | 
            Foreach {
                Remove-Item $_ -Force
            }

Write-Host -f Green 'Continue script'
```

Comment: Nice one, learned on Out-Gridview's -passthru. Remove-Item accepts input from the pipeline, so you might omit the foreach.

Comment: @LotPings if I remove `Foreach` I get error message: `Remove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.`

Comment: Also remove $_ amd the closing }

Comment: @LotPings sure, forgot to remove the `$_` :D How stupid of me.